# Hamiltonian of a system of an hydrogenic atom in EM field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, photons, absorption, photon-emission

In an interaction between an EM wave and an hydrogenic atom (atom with single electron) we have in the semi-classical approximation (I think that's what is called, basically treating classically EM radiation and the Coulomb potential) the Hamiltonian is written as:

$$ H = - \frac{h \nabla^2}{2m} - \frac{Ze^2}{4\pi \varepsilon r} -\frac{ihe A \nabla}{m} + \frac{e^2 A^2}{2m} $$

Why is the last term associated with a two-photon transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you treat $A$ as a classical background field, there is no photon. When $A$ is quantized, it becomes a superposition of annihilation and creation operators of photons, and then $A^2$ contains terms that correspond to two-photon process, like $(a^\dagger)^2$.

Comment: Wow that makes a lot of sense thank you very much! I remember in introductory course on quantum mechnics we wrote the harmonic oscillator potential as fuction of the operators of creation and annihilations, how would the vector potential be defined using those operators?

Comment: Quantization of EM needs a long discussion. Roughly speaking, each normal mode of EM wave (e.g. with a given wavevector and polarization) is quantized into a quantum harmonic oscillator. The "position" and "momentum" of this harmonic oscillator are essentially the $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{E}$ fields. I would recommend reading, e.g Shankar or Sakurai for more details.

Comment: That's satisfactory enough to understand where that claim comes from i'll eventually study the quantization of EM i hope. I suppose that any higher photon transmission (if exists) is explainable as power of $A$ (seems like new users cannot vote but i'm very grateful, that question annoyed me for days!)